# How to get local path of a folder from where i get all file list?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to `UWP`, I need to get list of all files which are stored in a folder by adding a folder to project.

```
foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\Resources\Shapes\") 
{ 
}
```

In above code `"Application.StartupPath"` is specific to `Forms`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StorageFolder class to access local files stored in the App folder.

See the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder).

Answer (score 0):

UWP is different from the general desktop application. UWP apps run in sandbox and have very limited access to the file system.

You would need to [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/). Please read the Rob's blog for more detailed information.

> I need to get list of all files which are stored in a folder by adding a folder to project.

If you want to get all files from a folder which is in the project's directory, you could use the location of the installed package. See the following code sample:

```
StorageFolder subfolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("subFolder");
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await subfolder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

But, if you want to add files to this folder, it's not allowed. The installed package is read-only.

In UWP, you could choose to write data in [application data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata). For example, you could add files in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.